# In MATLAB, find zero crossings within a threshold, given a vector of data

Tags: matlab, time, signal-processing, feature-detection

I have written a function in MATLAB to count the number of zero crossings given a vector of signal data. If I find a zero crossing, I also check whether the absolute difference between the two vector indices involved is greater than a threshold value - this is to try to reduce the influence of signal noise.

```
    zc = [];
    thresh = 2;
    for i = 1:length(v)-1
        if ( (v(i)>0 && v(i+1)<0) || (v(i)<0 && v(i+1)>0) ) && abs(v(i)-v(i+1)) >= thresh
            zc = [zc; i+1];
        end
    end
    zcCount = length(zc);
```

I used the vector from the zero crossings function here to test it: http://hips.seas.harvard.edu/content/count-zero-crossings-matlab

```
    A = [-0.49840598306643,
         1.04975509964655,
        -1.67055867973620,
        -2.01437026154355,
         0.98661592496732,
        -0.06048256273708,
         1.19294080740269,
         2.68558025885591,
         0.85373360483580,
         1.00554850567375];
```

It seems to work fine but is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result? E.g. on the above webpage, they simply use the following line to calculate zero crossings:

```
    z=find(diff(v>0)~=0)+1;
```

Is there a way to incorporate the threshold check into something similarly efficient?

Comment: You should look at all the "find zero crossing" questions linked over there ---->

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
zeroCrossIndex=diff(v>0)~=0
threshholdIndex = diff(v) >= thresh;
zcCount = sum(zeroCrossIndex & threshholdIndex)
```

Comment: That's great @Dan. I can even use `abs(diff(v) >= thresh` in the second line to check threshold either side of zero.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can add some more flexibility for non-zero crossings be replacing `diff(v>0)` with diff(v>val)` where val the crossing point of interest. Be sure to add the abs(diff(v)>=thresh suggested by @humbleHacker